# React Axios Header Jwt not sending

Tags: javascript, .net, api, axios, jwt

When I send a request to the API with the same token from the postman, the request drops successfully without being authorized. but when i try with axios i get stuck on 401 error.

```
Axios.post('https://localhost:7261/api/'+url,{ headers: {Authorization: `Bearer  ${token}`}, ContentType: 'application/json' }, value,{ withCredentials: true })).data`
```

token:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYmYiOjE2NTg5OTU4MjYsImV4cCI6MTY1OTA4MjIyNiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwIiwiaXNBdXRoZW50aWNhdGVkIjp0cnVlLCJuYW1lIjoiQmF0dWhhbiIsInJvbGVzIjpbIlnDtm5ldGljaSJdLCJtYWlsIjoiYmF0dV82NDA3QGhvdG1haWwuY29tLnRyIiwiY29tcGFueUlkIjoxLCJ1c2VySWQiOjh9.989X7Fvvq2HHTkzw_TwuDjTYdFASDOU-Bcq8vE_duqE

api:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Yönetici")]
        public HttpStatusCode CreateTask(Common.DTO.TaskDTO task)
        {
            if (task == null) return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

            DOMAIN.Models.Task taskDomain = _mapper.Map<DOMAIN.Models.Task>(task);
            List<DOMAIN.Models.Document> document = new List<DOMAIN.Models.Document>();
            foreach (var item in task.documentDTOs)
            {
                document.Add(_mapper.Map<DOMAIN.Models.Document>(item));
            }

            taskDomain.Documents = document;


            if (_taskServices.CreateTask(taskDomain) == 1)
                return HttpStatusCode.OK;
            else
                return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }
```

as I said. When I send a request from postman with the same token, a successful result is returned. I am getting 401 error with axios.

Comment: you're using `axios.post(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)` ... there is no such pattern for axios.post with 4 arguments! it's at most `url, data, config` ... my guess is you want `axios.post(url, value, {headers, withCredentials})`

Comment: i.e. that last argument would be `{ headers: { Authorization: \`Bearer  ${token}\` }, ContentType: 'application/json', withCredentials: true }`

Comment: @JaromandaX it happened. thanks.

Comment: what happened??